# Why this polymorphic assignment does not work in typed observableArray in Knockout?

Tags: typescript, knockout.js

Let's have class `A` and subclass `B`. I want to assign an array of `B`'s to array of `A`'s. With normal arrays it works as expected, but with `ko.ObservableArray` it fails.

```ts
import ko from "knockout";

class A {};
class B extends A {b = 1};

const a: A = new B();                // no problem here
const aArr: A[] = [] as B[];         // no problem here
// COMPILER PROBLEM ON LAST LINE!
const aObs: ko.ObservableArray<A> = ko.observableArray() as ko.ObservableArray<B>;
```

The compiler is not satisfied with the last line, it shows this error:

```
Type 'ObservableArray<B>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableArray<A>'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'A[] | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'B[] | null | undefined'.
      Type 'A[]' is not assignable to type 'B[]'.
        Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'B'.
```

But clearly I do not want to assign `A` to `B`, but `B` to `A`.

How to cope with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is [`ObservableArray<T>`](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/6085335/build/types/knockout.d.ts#L206-L208) is [contravariant](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance) on it's type variable `T`. And that's why it tries to assign types in reverse direction.

While you can freely assign `B` to `A` (because `B extends A` and you even don't have to declare it as `extends`) when it goes in covariant position:

```ts
class A { }
class B { b = 1 }

const a: A = new B();
const aArr: A[] = [] as B[];
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mbk53W)

You cannot assign a function taking argument of those types in the same direction. Only in the opposite one.

```ts
type Fn<T> = (t: T) => void

const fn1: Fn<A> = null as unknown as Fn<B> // error here
const fn2: Fn<B> = null as unknown as Fn<A> // no error
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mplOzm)

---

In case you're absolute sure the assignment is perfectly fine and the compiler unnecessary restricts you. You may take the responsibility on yourself and typecast it for the expected type:

```ts
import ko, { ObservableArray } from 'knockout'

class A {};
class B extends A {b = 1};

const bObs: ObservableArray<B> = ko.observableArray()
const aObs: ObservableArray<A> = bObs as unknown as ObservableArray<A>;
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N9A3JN)

---

You can also globally switch off contravariance check for fn's arguments with [`--strictFunctionTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictFunctionTypes) option. Though most of the time that's quite usefull check.

Comment: OK I get the theory. Now the remaining question - how to cope with it? I know that the code by design will mutate the array only on the "B"-side - only push `B` instances and never ever anything else. There is another array of `C`s, `D`s, etc... and all are suppose to be passed as `A`s only for computation without modification. So semantically the "covariant approach" will be correct. Is there any code solution for this? I can add a ts-ignore flag but it seems a little rough...

Comment: I'm not aware about any 'safe' approach to fix this. You may use `as` cast if you're absolutely sure nothing bad will happen. `ts-ingore`/`ts-expect-error` to suppress errors. Or `strictFunctionTypes` option to disable those kind of checks alltogether.

Comment: I'd suppose `as` is a kind of 'better' approach. You just take responsibility on yourself because you know better (or at least believe it :)) than compiler about overall relations in your code.